# Conditional check for strings not giving the behavior I expect

Tags: python, database, python-3.x, sqlite

I have an SQLite database which I am reading data from using Python. I connect to the database and then store the whole comment column into a list called output. Each entry in the list is a string, I want to isolate the entries in list which only contain the string '[deleted]'.

To do this I am using a loop to index into the list and then for each point I compare the string to at index i to the string '[deleted]', if the string is '[deleted]' it should set a corresponding value of 1 at index i in a vector of zeros called deleted flag. The code I am using is below:

```
deletedFlag = np.zeros((len(output),1))
for i in range(0,len(output)):
        if (output[i] == "[deleted]"):
            deletedFlag[i] = 1
```

The issue is that output[i] == '[deleted]' never returns true and therefore never sets the corresponding deletedFlag[i] = 1

Investigating further and printing output[i] to the console for a value of i I know to contain the '[deleted]' string returns a slightly different string than I expect:

```
>> print(output[3])
>> ('[deleted]',)
```

However even if I  change my string comparison to be the same as the printed value I still get the same behavior of the deletedFlag vector remaining at all zeros:

```
deletedFlag = np.zeros((len(output),1))
for i in range(0,len(output)):
        if (output[i] == "('[deleted]',)"):
            deletedFlag[i] = 1
```

Looking at the first four database entries using DB Browser shows the following taken from a screenshot and it is line 4 of the comment column I am trying to identify:

[image]

I assume I am just doing the string comparison wrong but for the life of me I can't work out what it should be and I have tried most permutation of brackets and inverted commas I can think of.  I understand that this is probably a really basic issue but any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Check the return value again.  Is it actually a string?  It also could be a tuple with `'[deleted]'` as the first element.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: Thanks, yes you were right it was tuple. I will update the question with a working example and solution so it is easier to follow

Answer (score 1):

Well ... that printed `output[3]` kinda looks like a half filled tuple. so, you might need to check `output[i][0]` instead.

Also, i'd suggest using __contains to do the string comparison and you don't need to write `range(0,n)`: by default it starts at zero so a simple `range(n)` does the exact same thing ;>

```
deletedFlag = np.zeros((len(output),1))
for i in range(len(output)):
    if output[i][0].__contains("deleted"):
        deletedFlag[i] = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, yep the issue was that it was tuple, by using output[i][0] this then worked correctly. Thanks for the other pointers!